# How to create an Escape Button

Tags: javascript, button, escaping

I have a website that needs and `escape` button that works just like [this one](http://idvsa.org/) (left on page)

I attempted to see how they have written the code, but can't locate the JavaScript or jQuery file that the button references.

When you click the floating button, it sends you to a different website, then disables the back button and removes the website from your history.

Unfortunately clueless as to how to begin to write this script.

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648829/fastest-exit-strategy-for-a-panic-button-in-crisis-abuse-websites

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome developer console, you can find out that their function is called escape_page. And you type 'escape_page' into the javascript console, the function shows up as follows:

```
function escape_page() {
//here we will first set an array of site withc we can use in the function
var safeSites = [ 
    "http://google.com", 
    "http://facebook.com",
    "http://idahostatesman.com",
    "http://youtube.com",
    "http://groupon.com",
    "http://livingsocial.com", 
    "http://cnn.com",
    "http://twitter.com",
    "http://yahoo.com",
    "http://bing.com",
    "http://digg.com",
    "http://reddit.com"
];

var randSitesArray = randomizeArray(safeSites);

var randSite = randSitesArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*safeSites.length)];

for (var i = 0; i < randSitesArray.length; i++) {
    // for each array items fill history
    //History.pushState(null, "Title", randSitesArray[i]);
    History.replaceState({state:i}, randSitesArray[i], null);
    History.pushState({state:i}, randSitesArray[i], null); 
}
//  redirect to one of the websites witht he randomized array
//alert(randSite);
window.location.replace(randSite);
}
```

HOWEVER, I do not see any licensing disclaimer in their website, so *don't* copy paste their code.

Comment: Thank you.  I never copy paste code, I just look at it for inspiration.  Thanks for finding that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location.replace method on any clickable element.  Using just javaScript:

```
<input id="escape_button" type="button" value="escape" onClick="window.location.replace('http://www.google.com')" />
```

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp):

> The replace() method replaces the current document with a new one.
>
> The difference between this method and assign(), is that replace() removes the URL of the current document from the document history, meaning that it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate back to the original document.

Comment: Unfortunately this never worked fully cross-browser, and still provides back button functionality in Chrome latest, nor IE8. Please don't use this functionality and think you're fully protecting your users. It's a false sense of security.