# Fastest exit strategy for a Panic Button in Crisis/Abuse Websites?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a website for a Women's Abuse Resource Center. A lot of centers like this have what is referred to by the centers as a "Panic Button". An example of a basic one is found [here](http://www.fscic.org/) at the top of every page in the green bar.

The idea of the link or button is for if a women was looking at this website for help, and their abuser or someone they didn't want to know walked in the room, it allows for a fast escape. Sometimes a link is much faster then closing a browser window and that can be suspicious.

The problem I see is that most buttons I see doing this just send you to google or something like that. I am going to do something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.msn.com/#news" rel="noreferrer">LEAVE WEBSITE NOW!</a>
```

or

```
<a href='data:text/html;charset=utf-8, <html><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=&#39;http://www.msn.com/#news/&#39;"></html>'>LEAVE WEBSITE NOW!</a>
```

A link like that will scroll you to some actual content. Its not a blank Google search but is also not a very specific thing that could be seen as suspicious.

I know that blocking the referrer is good but even with that solution you can hit the back button on your browser and your caught. For this problem I thought I could do something this:

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:goNewWin()" rel="noreferrer">LEAVE WEBSITE NOW!</A>
```

JavaScript

```
function goNewWin() {
    window.open("backbuttonnewpage.html",'TheNewpop','toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); 
    self.close()
}
```

I am posting because there are lives at risk with this and I need something that is as close to a total solution as can be. How would you do this?

**UPDATE- 3-26-14:**
I ran some of the educational ideas posted here by the resource center I am working with and here was their answer. "It takes extreme courage for our users to even come on our website. When they come they are looking for a fast easy resource to get out of a possibly life threatening situation. They would not have the time or the mental capacity in most cases to educate themselves on a safe way to browse our website. When presented with the idea of a "panic button", when done properly, has seemed to be a resource that is always asked for by most victims that we treat."

After reading a lot of the ideas here it seems like a total solution would be a large button that floats in a constant position on left hand side. When the page loads it loads another site in the background (maybe an ajax call) so that clicking the button just removes the overlaying frame. This will mean no load time when clicked. To avoid a back button press of the browser it seems like telling the browser not to cache is necessary as well as possibly using `replaceState` on every page change to disable a back button that reveals this site.

This is still very much a technical question. The debate helps very much but I still need a working technical solution. Anyone think they are able to get all these ideas together into something functional? Ill be working on it right away myself and will post anything I come up with. Thanks all.

Comment: I would start by either clearing or obscuring the current page (using javascript) when the link is clicked (because it can take some time for a link to be followed...)

Comment: With `window.open()` and `window.close()` you may find pop-up blockers getting in your way... I found another similar site that has a "leave quickly" link: http://www.riversofhope.org/home.html - it uses the same method, just redirecting to Google.

Comment: @mellamokb Linked page did not appear to prominently display `leave quickly` link ? Could not find in under 2 min ? Prospectively, simply _close browser entirely, certain that `clear recent history` or `clear browsing data on close` set to true_ ?

Comment: I'd default to using Google as the default, but perhaps enable the user to enter their own preferred destination, storing their choice in a cookie.

Comment: Interestingly, in the linked page, the "click here to leave quickly" link seems inaccessible on iPad, [obscured by social media buttons](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4aTwT.jpg)...about the worst ux decision I've seen in recent history :/

Comment: Agree with David Thomas about preference w/ default to google -- using MSN would by itself be suspicious in my house.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: If you are open for JS solution, you may also add some key combination like `CTRL+SHFT+RIGHT ARROW` that could redirect to another random site (you can have 4-5 random URLs and may redirect to either one). This will be much faster for a user to get out of site.

Comment: If you want to make this better, I'd also make it work using gestures: http://jgestures.codeplex.com/ On a phone this would allow it to work much quicker.

Comment: Ohh, also add a hide button for those whom are just annoyed by it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the last javascript solution won't work for the majority of users the first time - it'll pop up a message asking if they want to allow popups from this site or not.  You should consider a solution that works for everyone, everywhere, everytime, or not offer one at all because you're providing a false sense of security.  The google link has it's problems, yes, but it's actually a very good solution, partly because google always loads very, very quickly.

Comment: Putting the button at the top seems like an awful placement. Think about fitts' law! You have a thin strip that somebody has to hit, and if they overshoot they won't hit it. Ridiculous. Put it on the left, where the majority of users can take advantage of the effectively infinite size. (Right could be scrollbar on some displays, bottom is default taskbar, top is default tab bar. Anybody savvy enough to have changed these defaults probably knows `^w`)

Comment: This has to be one of the first questions on SO that probably has dealt with life and death.

Comment: I think the button should be quite large, and hard to miss. It should be stuck to the page, so that it remains in place as the page scrolls, every ready to be clicked without having to search for it. Having an alternative keyboard shortcut to go along with it isn't a bad idea either. As for what happens when they click this button, have a look at my answer.

Comment: @AdamDavis Not always. Read my answer for reasons why it might not load at all.

Comment: What about just having the user right-click anywhere at all on the page instead of left-clicking on a button? Would take merely a split second, not much thought required. I don't know how to implement that though. Just a suggestion.

Comment: this is not a technical question, it is polling for opinion on UX issues, it should be moved to UX it is a waste of space and time here! And a initiated by a flawed assumption to begin with, all the "discussiony" non-answers and comments proves this!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson no I think this is a technical question. He's specifically asking for a panic button, people are just giving (mostly) UX answers.

Comment: @TrafficPrints. If you build your entire website as an SPA (Single Page Application), then you'll only ever have one browser history record to overwrite so you don't need to use `replaceState` every time a new "page" is loaded.

Comment: @TrafficPrints Also, what type of server will you be using? My strategy needs to be implemented in the server as well, and I can show you how to do it.

Comment: @staticx I know lol, I'm so stressed that if my solution has flaws it could potentially kill someone. Is this what civil engineers feel like most of the time?

Comment: It's just software. I have written mission critical stuff for years. I never worried. Good luck

Comment: @Entbark interesting idea, not tough to detect the right mouse click, but it's still a non-standard and simultaneously hidden solution. Maybe it would be a nice addition to other methods. I still vote for making sure the Esc key makes the page disappear.

Comment: This should be taken off hold. There are possible answers to the technical requirements.

Comment: I know many people have weighed in with opinions but this is a real technical question for me. Thank you for the opinions, they have helped, but I am actually doing this project and need a real working, functional solution. I feel that NicolasMoise has come up with the best solution so far but if this is to remain closed then I will not be able to have him weigh in as I try to use his provided solution.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**(ALMOST) FINAL EDIT**

**OK, I've read all the comments and this is what I think is the best solution but I've also thought of an ALL-LOCAL ALTERNATIVE. I'm open to further improvement/discussion**

```
var panic= function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
       //this clears the current html in the body 
       //making it look like the page is loading
    
    if(...){ //check if replaceState is supported so no error is thrown
        var title="Decoy Article Title",
        url="/decoypage"; //another endpoint on your server that gives the decoy website
        window.history.replaceState("", title , url); //replace current history entry
    }

    //should be pretty fast up to this point
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com"); //load the google page or my alternative.
}
```

I put an example on my AWS instance at 54.186.79.95 Go to that page, click the button, visit another page, then hit back, you're now on 54.186.79.95/decoywebsite and there's no record of you being on 54.186.79.95/, if cache is disabled, your server will see the "../decoywebsite" request and send a decoy page. Unfortunately, you can't modify the entire domain so you would need the domain to be not suspicious.

If you want to get rid of the page content, I believe the best way is to use `document.body.innerHTML='';`. You are still technically on the page but all the content is gone.

Next step is to modify your browser history. `window.history.replaceState` ([link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)) is an HTML5 feature that can modify your history without doing a page reload or a request to your server. It's pretty fast but only works on modern browsers. When the user clicks the panic button, we will replace the current page in his history with a fake url.

If the abusive user clicks back, your server (Php, python, whatever) will receive a request with your fake url. So you need to have another endpoint in your server (Let me know if you don't understand endpoints). Make a benign article, recipe, or weather report with a similar look and feel to your original website in order to avoid suspicion if the abuser got a quick glance at the website. Also make sure the browser's doesn't cache by using the `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`tag.

**Additional Remarks**

- Ideally your entire website (except your decoy article of course) should be an SPA (Single Page Application) so that it only ever produces one browser history record and you only have to modify that one.
- At the end of the day, I don't think you can't make a panic button that's 100% foolproof, there's gonna be ways around it. You just have to find one with an acceptable level of security and convenience.

### ANOTHER ALTERNATIVE: LOCALLY CHANGE THE INCRIMINATING INFO AND MODIFY BROWSER HISTORY

I was also thinking if **instead of loading google**, if it's not best to actually **transform your site locally with innocent info**. This looks less suspicious than loading google (everyone does that) and you can do it all locally without reloading the page.

When they click the panic button, you do some fast (and cross-browser compliant) DOM manipulation to change the incriminating info on your website and make it look innocent (maybe just change the text, it has to be fast). This way, it's all done locally which in the vast majority of browsers today is almost instant. You don't have to worry about reload/servers because the scripts should already be loaded and ready to go. If you keep the same look and feel it looks like the user was just navigating to a different page of the website. Don't make it too obvious from the look of your website that it's a crisis website. Of course, you make it impossible to navigate back to the original content. I would also make it clear on the panic button what the strategy is so that the user doesn't freak out.

I would still try to change the browser history and buy another domain that hosts a copy of the decoy page, as in the previous example. Not only if the domain name is suspicious, but in case the abusive user hits refresh or goes back in his history. You should make your entire website an SPA because you can only modify your current entry, not your past history. Of course, this would still only work in HTML5 browsers, just make sure no error is thrown and the other part of the scripts still runs in old browsers.

What do people think? any weaknesses to this? What would be good content to replace with?

Comment: Angular/Backbone don't do anything you can't do with native JS.

Comment: Suggested edit: You should clarify that the #foo ref/fragment isn't sent to the server. 

You can prove this by checking what's sent using cURL:
`curl -v http://example.org/#/foo`

[RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) "... the fragment identifier is separated from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced solely by the user agent ..."

Comment: @JoeLiversedge yea you're probably right. However, it is possible to get rid of the hashbang (`#`) and therefore have your server see the fragments. Some JS frameworks do this out of the box. I'm not that familiar with `window.history` for a pure JS solution but anyone's welcome to edit my post. The current app I'm working on (Angular + Express) works like this: the server doesn't see when I navigate within my app but if I refresh or exit and hit back, my server will see a full request.

Comment: I don't think you should use a framework in this case because you want the exit script to be as light as possible (no need for DOM manipulation, just push the state without the hashbang and get out)

Comment: @JoeLiversedge k I edited my answer to get rid of the hashbang. However, this may not work in older browsers so you might also consider `location.hash` which has more support.

Comment: I do like the idea that the history can be covered up automatically, but you can't be sure that the user is using an HTML5 compliant browser. Likely, if they aren't tech savvy, they won't be.

Comment: @crush, yes that is a drawback of my strategy that I pointed out. The redirect to Google should work no matter what. There's `location.hash` which is pretty similar to `window.history.pushState` and has wider support across browsers. I'm not sure if you can use that to spoof history in the same way.

Comment: If anyone has any pre-HTML5 ideas for modifying browser history, I'm all ears.

Comment: @NicolasMoise you can criticize my idea as far as you want, but I think you miss problems in your argument. Based on caniuse - there are 27% of people who can not have history api, moreover your code brings me back to page http://www.imagesup.net/?di=3139586676411 . Also no matter what I can see it in the history. So basically you provided partial solution which does not work.

Comment: @Salvador, yes I already mentioned the HTML5 compatibility issue, but thanks for pointing it out again. Also, in the image you linked you'll notice that the `/foo` is added to the url so really it's not the same page which is the whole point of my strategy.

Comment: @Salvador from your own image: http://imgur.com/wCfy4zn , now your server should see the `/foo` request and render a harmless article instead of the regular page. If the abusive user hits back and the website looks nothing like the OP's website (which he probably got a quick look at) that would be suspicious.

Comment: @NicolasMoise Not a bad idea for the crisis prevention website to own another domain that seems unrelated, and design its look & feel with switching covertly in mind.

Comment: @crush, My solution doesn't really switch domains. I was thinking more of having a relatively non-suspicious domain (e.g. www.xyzfoundation.com) and then switch the history to www.xyzfoundation.com/harmless-atricle. Switching domains could work, but hopefully it doesn't slow down the whole exit process (Making additional requests is a no-no, I'm not sure if changing domains would do that), extensive testing needs to be done for sure.

Comment: @NicolasMoise That's why my solution suggested to preload the exit domain, so that it's already ready to present instantly.

Comment: @crush, I don't know if you can modify the domain in an already existing browser history entry which is what you would need ideally.

Comment: Cmon from the same image you can notice that there is a huge picture Crisis Intervention Center? Does this sound suspicious? Or you think that a guy will ignore it and will tell something like "oh she has foo in a bar - that's ok". If you have to have additional domain and modify you code in some other way - why not to write about it?

Comment: @crush, ya I think pre-loading a website is definitely a possibility. I think OP needs to test both strategies on a lot of different browsers/connections to see which one is safest/fastest. In your solution though, does the address change? What would happen if the user refreshes the page instead of pressing back, wouldn't he get the original page then?

Comment: @Salvador, I get what you're saying but I think you don't understand my strategy. Maybe re-read my answer and comments. If you're still confused I can try to explain it better.

Comment: @crush, In summary, I think both our approaches work, but they're not foolproof by any mean. If we try to find and discuss their respective weaknesses, then OP can make an informed decision.

Comment: @crush Last comment I swear lol, wouldn't it be better to use `document.body.innerHTML=''` as an alternative to pre-loading the decoy website? That way when the user clicks the button, the first things it does is clear the HTML in the page. This can't be slower than switching frames and there's nothing suspicious about a blank page that eventually loads another website. Also this has the benefit or making your website lighter to load (which is a non-issue when compared to saving lives, but still...)

Comment: You could do that, but what if the Internet is severed at the time the button is pressed, then you're just looking at a blank website. No one is going to believe you're sitting there statring at a blank screen. Preloading the page means all the code is available and rendered. Just needs to be shown. Can't get faster than that, and no chance the content won't be there

Comment: @NicolasMoise Would you mind showing us this in a working example like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @TrafficPrints To which strategy? I proposed an alternative.

Comment: Alright well I didn't know if this would work with jsfiddle's iframes so I put in on my AWS instance. here it is http://54.186.79.95/ Go to that page, click the button, visit another page, then hit back, you're now on http://54.186.79.95/decoywebsite, if cache is disabled, your server will see the "../decoywebsite" request and send a decoy page. Unfortunately, you can't modify the entire domain so you would need the domain to be not suspicious.

Comment: @NicolasMoise I might have a slightly enhanced angle on the "decoy page" scenario, which could eliminate the potential pitfalls with the redirect scenario, and a couple of other ideas that might be useful (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22678664/618649).

Answer (score 29):

Since you said that lives are at risks in your implementation, i strongly suggests educating the users to use multiple tabs instead of clicking on some panic buttons.

### My reasons being

1. In times of 'emergency', how long does it take for the user to move their hands to the mouse (assuming they lifted their hands to type or touch their hair or whatever they wanted to do), let's assume it took them -> **0.5 seconds**
2. In your example [site](http://www.fscic.org/), the green bar is actually very small, to be frank, not everyone is very accurate with their hand, eyes coordination (moreover mouse cursor acceleration might differ between OS'es and User Profiles), the user has to move the mouse to the "Panic" button and click, unless they are professional [FPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_shooter) gamers, it's likely to take them another -> **1-2 seconds**
3. My last variable assumption is, if your script involves loading remote resources, for e.g. www.google.com, you can put lives at risk by assuming that the browser is

   - Modern
   - Has scripts enabled
   - Network speed & latency is optimal
   - Caches are primed.

If you are going to load remote resources, i suggests you to insert a div with z-index: -1 and some dummy web contents. On click, move their z-index higher to overlap everything on screen.

So if we assume you load a remote resource and with all the unknown variables, we can assume the time taken to be -> **0.5 - 10 seconds**

If you are going to write a program that might kill someone, i strongly suggests you not to take the risk of doing something that might take 2 - 12 seconds to save them.

### Educate your users by putting a banner with instructions

1. Open a tab that wouldn't threaten their own lives (e.g. google.com, msn.com, yahoo.com)
2. Open another tab with your site
3. Navigate normally on your site
4. In times of emergency, press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> for Google Chrome, [IE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/internet-explorer-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=windows-7), Firefox, Opera (please confirm for other major browsers)

If you get the whole idea, press ctrl + w vs your planned solution, i can certainly guarantee that <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> is going to be faster.

Comment: as for the history trail, there's In-Private mode for IE and Incognito mode for chrome

Comment: I think this is a good idea, as it is definitely faster/safer but it's not a replacement for a panic button. You can't expect all visitors to have read and understood your tutorial especially if it's there first time visiting. I think OP should have both a tutorial on safe-browsing techniques and a panic button.

Comment: Ctrl+W works in Firefox as well.

Comment: If i'm OP, i would design and implement something that would give the lowest risk, to be doubly safe, the panic button can still exist, but as stated in my proposed answer, he should use a hidden div that display static and 'neutral' content which will factor out unknown variables, if possible, minimize the mechanical variable of moving the mouse and clicking, by using hoykeys, maybe pressing any keyboard keys in rapid succession like "aksjdlasd", an eventlistener that monitors the keystrokes timespan within 1000ms of > 5 keypresses to display the hidden div would be good

Comment: @LeeGary Firefox has private-browsing too which would work the same way.

Comment: The target audience is clearly not very tech savy, and in a very emotional/stressed situation. Educating about how to use a browser in the most stealthy way (probably in a language they don't speak very well) is currently their least concern. And what do they do if in that very moment they are being educated someone comes in? While it certainly is a good idea in general for them to know e.g. ctrl-w, can you guarantee that they remember? A highly visible "panic button" is a good and intuitive help you can give them. Everything else can only be addition.

Comment: While a good idea, `Ctrl-W` is easily mis-pressed to be `Ctrl-Q`, which quits the browser altogether and that is probably far more suspicious than just displaying *Google*. I manage to do this by accident at least once a week and am thankful we don't have a swear jar at work, you can only assume that a person under pressure is far more likely to do that.

Comment: I don't know why this is voted up. This answer is ridiculous, while it would be nice if everyone knew proper safe browsing techniques. You can't expect someone who's in a state of distress and probably visiting your site for the fist time to know/read/understand this.

Comment: @GeorgeDubass What if you displayed a message at the top of the page, that had a browser specific message in it. Google specific message: "Open a new tab to a benign site. In panic: press CTRL+W to switch to this other tab." I agree, it is a bit much to ask someone in an irrational state to think rationally.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this was voted up. This is a terrible and off-topic answer that introduces further unnecessary complexity to OP's original question. A better suggestion would be a bigger and more explicit banner, not an extra tab. Stop thinking about this problem from an experienced developer or superuser's perspective that has mastered keyboard shortcuts. My mom wouldn't care, or more explicitly, won't understand keyboard shortcuts, and this is precisely who it's targeted to.

Comment: Not to add, like @crush mentions, you're asking a user to perform a logical operation in an irrational state.

Comment: @crush, NO, this is NOT A REPLACEMENT FOR A PANIC BUTTON. Your method only works if they've already read  and understood your instructions which would eliminate first-time visitors and non tech savvy users. The  panic button is an easy escape that everyone can understand.

Comment: @GeorgeDubass If it's a banner that stays on the screen as they scroll, I'm not sure how they'd miss it. Regardless, I agreed with your point... No reason to shout. Your opinion isn't more important than anyone elses. You don't have to be tech savvy to follow on-screen instructions.

Comment: Someone mentioned a sidebar (like an ad banner), which is infinitely large. I like that idea more.

Comment: Personally, I think that most computer users can manage to press Ctrl+W at the same time. The question, though, is if that's more effective than pressing a button on screen. If users are reading a website telling them how they can get help, they are more likely to have their hand on the mouse than the keyboard. Likewise, non-tech savvy users often are hunt-and-peck typers, and would expend much more time and effort finding the Ctrl and W key in a frantic panic state. Not to mention, it would likely serve to tip off the offender that they were trying to escape.

Comment: I disagree with the tab solution. If someone is not accurate enough to click on a big button (assuming you make yours big), I don't see how this person will be accurate enough to press Ctrl + right key (which is more complicated by the way). But I do agree with not trusting the 2 sec loading and creating a <div> with dummy data that will be put in front if you press the panic button.
I would add that to activate the panic button, putting the mousing around it should be enough (no click needed), better be safe than sorry)...

Comment: @crush, sorry about the caps. It just baffles me that OP asked "how to implement a panic button" and yet people seem to be answering "how to safely browse the web". That's SO for you I guess.

Comment: @GeorgeDubass It seems that there intention is that browsers already have measures that can be used in times of panic, and that users just need be made aware of these mechanics instead of trying to implement it ones-self. I agree, though, that they are underestimating how computer-illiterate people can be. EVERYONE can click a mouse button, but not everyone can find Ctrl + W and hit it in 0.4s.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are slower than the mouse for a lot of people.

Comment: @user2820464, that's because we don't spend our own personal time to give inferior advices, i'm trying to give truthful personal opinion and bothered to give this question another 2-3 mins of my thoughts. If you are a doctor, someone walks in and asks you, how do i kill myself in the least painful manner? Would you straight up give them your medical advices? or would you spend a little more time to find out more about the problem?

Comment: @Lee Gary: Except this is not walking in to see a doctor. This is about someone walking in on the user. This is about a situation the user likely has little to no control over (or neglected to take measures to prevent), which is completely different.

Comment: @BoltClock should all the answers that don't mention or suggest removing the panic button be flagged as off-topic  because even OP has clearly stated he's not looking for alternatives/tutorials on safe browsing?

Comment: @NicolasMoise: Just downvote them on the basis that they missed the point.

Comment: Lee, no offense but it's important to think of a UX-type question like this in the perspective of a user, not a superuser or programmer. This question is a bit multidisciplinary, but your answer replied in a UX (albeit a *poor* UX in the perspective of an irrational state user that is of an abuse victim) sense while the original question was "how to do it". My "why was this upvoted" was based on the fact that your solution was off-topic/irrelevant, and at the same time an inferior user-experience based on the target audience.

Answer (score 23):

***This answer assumes that History and Address Bar aren't an Issue. At least, not immediately.***

## Scenario

Julie is a victim of spousal abuse. She is on the internet searching for help, and she comes to your website: http://www.crisisprevention.com (fictional for this answer)

As she is perusing your site, she hears her spouse approaching the room rapidly. She panics. Fortunately, you have a nice, large button, fixed to the page as she scrolls.

***She clicks this button and ...***

#### It takes her to Google.com

I dislike this approach for the following reason: no one is going to believe that you are simply sitting in front of your computer staring at the Google search prompt. Believe me. I've tried it before.

I used to keep a tab open with the Google prompt, and if I was browsing off-topic at work stuff, I'd switch to the Google tab so that no one was the wiser. It worked...sort of. Until people started to question why I was staring at the Google search screen all day.

I've since started opening a tab with various work projects in different states. Usually, stuff I'm working on anyways in between browsing. So, now I'm actually getting some work done! It doesn't take a tech genius to figure out this approach, which is why @LeeGary's answer may be the best.

#### It takes her ... it's still taking her ... oh Internet connection problems

Here's a reality you need to be prepared for. Perhaps the Internet Connection gets interrupted at the moment she is panicking. The current content stays displayed on the page while she waits for the HTTP GET request to get content it can start rendering...only, no content is being retrieved. The Internet connection is disconnected. This could happen for any number of reasons:

- Spouse disconnected it.
- Server being contacted is under extreme load.
- Browser is running shy on memory.
- ISP is having issues.
- Dial-up connection/disconnect (yes these still exist).
- Computer is just slow.
- DNS server is down.

The reasons go on and on why the browser might choke when she hits the panic button, and it tries to move her to a new site.

## Serve an Alternative Website Instantly

My solution suggests that you preload a website in the background of your site. Load it into a `<div>` and hide it behind your normal site. If it's a large bit of content, then you might consider hiding it with `z-index` instead of `display: none`. This way it will be pre-rendered (*I believe, could be wrong here*).

Now, it doesn't matter if her Internet connection is down. She already has the content. There is no latency involved with an HTTP GET request. It simply displays immediately.

If address bar is a concern, you might still be able to mitigate that by serving an alternative website that correlates to your domain.

For example, take the fictitious (for this answer) domain: http://www.crisisprevention.com

You could serve up some alternative article that relates to say, solving the world hunger crisis.

The idea here is that it's the initial first glance that is the most damning. When the spouse walks in and he sees her navigating away to Google.com, with that panicked look about her, he's going to suspect something is up and be more inclined to investigate. Likewise, it could be even worse if she's caught in the act of trying to hide her actions because the HTTP GET request was slow or fails.

Comment: It would be good if the alternative website could have the same look and feel as the real website: colours, layout. So if the abuser saw the site out of the corner of his eye as he came into the room, it would just appear to flicker a little - not to change to another site.

Comment: I like this thought process. I would like to add a thought that we would need to use JavaScript to trigger the toggle, so we should have a backup option for the possibility (however insignificant) that there is a JS error or if JS is disabled to have an actual href set on the link so it does go somewhere instead of re-anchoring to the top of the page (and then just return false on the click event in JS).

Comment: From a design perspective (in response to micapam), I agree entirely, and would add that designers creating sites where a panic button is needed should avoid colors that stand out (saturation and uniqueness) and use white/light grey secondary tones with a shade of neutral/common primary color.

Answer (score 16):

There are some big problems with panic button:

- it is hard to click on it (you have to be accurate)
- it takes time to select it (and a huge amount of time if you are on laptop without a mouse)
- it saves you in history
- it is accessible via back button / backspace.

And how about the panicking random moves of a woman who is trying to quickly click on that button, when she was reading this. What if she will miss the button from the first attempt?

**So if there are really human lives that could be saved, this is kind of bad idea.**

The better way is to show them normal way of doing this (via some sort of help before you can possibly enter this site). It can be something like this:

Depending on the browser of a user you give them a list of steps to do which use only keyboard (no mouse at all). For example if she is on chrome.

1. open a website you like (FB, twitter, funny bunnies and pretend like you are doing something).
2. Press CRTL+SHIFT+N (opens incognito window) which will not allow backspace / history tricks
3. enter our site there (no copypasting to prevent checking what is inside of your buffer)
4. Read the stuff and always keep your hands on the keyboard close to CRTL and W
5. In case of emergency press CRTL+W
6. Continue starring at your FB, twitter, funny bunny

Surely you have to modify your explanation in appropriate language. But this way it is really hard to get caught. Also tell about sitting next to mirrors and other reflection surfaces like windows, glasses and other things. Ask them to try using these combination for some time to be familiar.

If human lives are involved, you have to be professional and do not use these panic buttons. Especially if it is so easy to teach people how to do it quicker and more secure.

**Answer to Nobius**

I got you point, thank you. But I disagree with your point. 
After a lot of campaign for it to be put on FB, have you actually seen it on FB? I have not. Nontechnical people are notorious for coming up with ridiculously bad ideas, some of which you might have experienced (preventing right click on banks' pages to improve security, 4 digit passwords to be easier to type from mobile phones). Pressing a button sounds easier, but look at my list of steps - the only thing you need to do in a stressful situation is pressing CTRL+W. You do not need to think in terms of tabs, modes and other things. This comes up to basic pattern - see someone, press CTRL+W. In my opinion this is not difficult at all and easy to remember. It is by far not harder than to remember to click on the button. Everything else you have to read in a normal atmosphere.

Pressing 2 buttons is MUCH faster than moving mouse, and it is really hard to miss them when your fingers are on them (do an experiment and put yourself in stress full situation and try to quickly click on that button). Also as I mentioned - I see at least four reasons how something can go wrong in `panic button` situation, whereas I see much less in reasons in CRTL+W. If humans lives are involve - you need to be professional.

**Answer to NicolasMoise**. Why people keep saying that you need to be tech savvy for pressing CTRL+W? I am not trying to show people how to use TOR, VPN, setting up encryption channel. This is just CTRL+W. People learned how to play angry birds to waist their time (which is much harder than to remember 2 buttons), so people can learn CRTL+W to save their lives. Tutorial can be shown in such a way that observer can not understand why you are reading this (when you see my list of steps, I do not believe that the first guess would be - ah this is for women abuse site).

But most probably giving people perception of false safety is much better. The answer is not off-topic. The person is asking how to implement panic button - and I am explaining why is the current way flawed and what can he do to do it better. It is on the same level as 'I want to make communication secure and I am using substitution cypher', yes you can improve the speed of his cypher and pretend that everything is OK, or you can show another way.

**One last attempt to explain my additional point**: you have to properly explain people the risks behind your approach. A good example when people suffered from not explaining problems properly was the issue with Belorussian bloggers, who thought that posting anonymously on the internet will make them untraceable from governmental repressions. The resource gave them false belief that they are save if they do not provide their real identity. They learned that this is not true in the hard way (when they were jailed for few years).

If someone would explain them the risk I think some of them would be happy to learn how to use any tool to save their next five years.

So why not to give women few options:

- you can use approach A right away, and here are the list of problems you can encounter.
- you can use approach B, which requires X minutes during the first time to read and to understand something. And then your list of possible problems decreases to a smaller list.

And let them decide what they want to do. This way they know the risks.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I disagree with your statement that it is ridiculous. A Panic button was something that a lot of charities and MPs in the UK campaigned for to be put on Facebook for teenagers who were being bullied online and didn't know who to get help from. Pressing a button is far easier to do in a stressful situation then having to commit to memory a long sequence of steps in advance and expect that nothing will go wrong when the situation arises.

Comment: @Nobilis that button did something and notified Facebook et al and not just revert - so it could take time - however the second point has some validity but as noted elsewhere needs to be big

Comment: @Mark well, OP did say it was a basic one :) But I'm trying to point out that the concept is known, familiar and in my opinion better suited to non-technical people. You know what a button is and you press it. Thinking in terms of tabs, private modes and keyboard shortcuts is arguably more complicated and less familiar to people who may only occasionally browse the web.

Comment: The audience is likely also ridiculous, being that they are in a highly irrational state. You can't expect them to think rationally.

Comment: @Salvador This answer is off-topic. It's like: "Oh you're in an abusive relationship and someone's monitoring your every moves, why not take some time to read and understand this long tutorial on proper browsing techniques so you'll be safe the next time you visit the site (that is assuming you weren't caught reading the tutorial)". Any system that assumes all its users are tech-savvy will inevitably fail. Again, we're not saying your method is bad or slow (it is actually faster and safer) but you can't expect every visitor to know this, and that's why you need a panic button.

Comment: No offense, but I don't think you understand the point me and Nobilis are trying to make. You're saying Ctrl+W is faster/safer, I agree. Where we disagree is you can't expect every visitor to know or remember Ctrl+W just because you mentioned it somewhere on your site. Also, OP specifically asked for a panic button.

Comment: @Salvador sorry, didn't see your last edit. Still though, I think a panic button is a necessity, anything else should be added on top.

Comment: Tell me more about how not suspicious using the private navigation is...
Would there be a panic button on this tutorial page?

Comment: @dyesdyes it is hard to tell that you are in private mode. Can you spot the private mode icon on the left upper corner on the top of your browser from normal distance.

Comment: @NicolasMoise I think that the proper way to do this would be a theoretical study to find out how people behave in situation and to compare two approaches. With button and with CTRL+W. See how fast people can learn pressing CTRL+W (may be this is really hard, and I can not understand it). And then to see the percentage of failures. If you think that this is a necessity - why not to tell people the risk behind this necessity. They might assume that panic button is completely fail free and would be really surprised if someone can show that with backspace you can see what they were doing.

Comment: @Salvador see my answer, it solves the backspace problem. I don't really get what a survey has to do with this and I doubt OP has the time to conduct one. There's nothing wrong with teaching people proper browsing techniques, but that doesn't replace or prevent you from having a panic button. Ideally you should have both.

Comment: @Salvador care to elaborate or provide an alternative?

Comment: @SalvadorDali using CTRL+W feels a little bit like asking the user to learn Emacs. Honestly, what on earth, *in the user's everyday world*, associates CTRL+W with escaping from a bad situation? CTRL+W doesn't *mean* anything to them prior to your instructions. They won't remember. Man, it's too bad there isn't just a key on the keyboard that says "Escape." Oh, wait, what is that "Esc" key? Esc, esca..., e-s-c-a-p-e... OH!  **ESCAPE**! I'm just saying. Forget CTRL+W, it IS in fact difficult for them to remember, and it also requires multiple mistake-prone keystrokes. Just use the Escape key.

Comment: Please stop thinking this as the perspective of a superuser or programmer. Asking a distressed abuse victim to perform logical operations in an irrational state is a ridiculously bad suggestion, and honestly an issue with most programmers these days where you're considering interfaces based on an experienced programmer/superuser rather than the run-of-the-mill user itself. This is one of the reasons why I highly recommend all my colleagues to take a short course in UX. STOP THINKING ABOUT THE INTERFACE/SOLUTION AS A PROGRAMMER.

Answer (score 10):

I think you still have a long journey ahead of you.

The reason for sending people to the Google page is that

1. it loads very fast
2. it's likely to be cached anyway
3. it renders *very* fast
4. it's really well optimized
5. did I mention it's fast?

The link you provided is slow.

If you want to provide a fast way of changing the screen then open your site in a frameset - with the cloak in a frame of height 0, and your site in a frame of full height. Then when the user clicks on the link swap around the frame heights and redirect to the top level window to the page already loaded.

Comment: I don't think google tolerates being loaded in a frame, but I do like the idea of the frame-switching cloak.

Comment: Not a bad idea, one issue I see though is that the url would stay the same.

Comment: Its still like 2-3 seconds (maybe more on slow internet), even with a hot cache.

Comment: @David: the OP didn't want to use Google.

Comment: @NicolasMoise: no the url in the address bar changes as soon as you issue the redirect

Comment: @Petah: eh? If it's already loaded in a frame then the speed of the internet connection doesn't matter

Comment: @symc: yes, I know. However the *answer*, on which I left that comment, explicitly suggests using Google. Which is unlikely to work, because Google (so far as I've found in experimentation recently) doesn't allow itself to be loaded in a frame.

Comment: I used to keep an open tab to Google open for when my boss would walk by. I'd switch to the Google tab, and stare at it until he was gone. Then I realized that Google's page is pretty devoid of content, and noone would actually think that it was acceptable or probable that I was spending most of my work day starting at a Google prompt.

Comment: @symcbean There is no guarantee that the Google page is always going to load very fast. In fact, I have definitely witnessed it *at time* loading very slowly. The user's browser could even lose internet connectivity, then what? It would be impossible to navigate away to another page at all.

Answer (score 5):

I am extending the scope of the question a bit, as clicking panic button does guarantee the user will not be caught.

There are multiple concerns in this problem that needs to be issued depending on the risk and how compute literate is the user.

As such, it might be a good idea to give the user some basic security knowledge in the friendliest way possible. Even though the user is under high stress, it is better for them to know what traces they can leave behind.

## Traces

### Browsing History

At any time the user uses your website without private browsing, it will leave very obvious traces. There is no proper way of detecting if the browser in running in private mode, but you can have a warning in the entrance that they should be switching to the private mode, **as well as** deleting the current history of entry. You can prepare some screenshots to for the user to follow to delete the history, (or if available, deleting only the entry to the site)

### Cookies

If you make use of cookies, the next person *can* get those cookies (even though they are expired), and can understand that this site has been used. If you can, make use of custom headers for authorization, which will leave no trace in the computer.
This can force you to change the structure of the application which might not be a good idea. Only setting cookies in the browser after you make sure the user is using a private browsing session.

### Caching

A tech-savy person can detect if the site has been visited if you make use of caching by opening the page and inspecting network. Make sure you explicitly instruct browser not to cache by using those headers in your responses:

```
'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
'Pragma: no-cache'
'Expires: 0'
```

### Back button

Upon changing pages, every page will be put in the current history (even in the private browsing session), allowing back button be used. If you can, make use of `replaceState` on every page change so that back button will be broken.

### Encryption

Use HTTPS to prevent eavesdropping. Note that DNS queries will still go unencrypted, but I don't think this will be a problem unless the user are leaking governmental stuff. If that's the case, a website wouldn't be safe enough anyway.

In general, those should be sufficient to remove the traces, also make sure you are not using other persistence layers like `localStorage`.

## Panic Button

This is a totally different problem and we need to include multiple things into our calculation.
First off, if this is a life threatening scenario, we must understand that the user will be under utter stress when they need to launch the `panic exit`. We don't know how the computer screen is positioned, and we cannot guess what is the user doing in the time of the panic.

### Screen Positioning Issues

The worst case would be that the screen would be positioned in a way that threat can see (from a distance) the screen and the site. If that is the case, the site should be designed in a way that it will look very similar to the `exit site` in order to remove any suspicion. Moving away from a different design to white Google will be noticeable even the screen is not directly visible by just comparing the colors that the screen was emitting between two sites (in a reasonably dark room).

### Exit Speed

If you just make a redirect, it might not be fast enough to make the change in time. You must preload the exit side in an iframe, and in the time of panic, you should put that in full screen, then make the redirection. This will both help on caching the exit sites static contents, and make the things look faster. Make sure you use `replaceState` instead of natural navigation to disable back button.

### Exit Routes

You must make sure that the exit routes will be available immediately and easily for the user to hit. I think the most possible two states are either *the user is typing*, or *the user is navigating*. Which means you should have both keyboard shortcut for exit and a big button in your HTML.

#### Keyboard Exit

I think using either hitting the ESC key twice should trigger it, or holding one of the big keys should (like space or enter). Either way, you should let the user know about this, and possibly, let them train themselves by trying.
Trying panic exits will both help them in anticipating behaviour on panic to make a good reasoning (Having the behaviour expected could be relieving), and they will be trained to do so, such that they will be more likely to do it properly in the panic time.

#### Mouse Exit

This is going to be pretty straightforward, have a big, different colored button that will trigger the panic.

### Where to Exit?

That depends on the case, by design it might be sensible to make a redirect to a commonly used, similarly designed site by default. It might also be sensible to allow the user to choose the exit site by themselves (after making a sane default).

## Notes

- If the user is using private browsing and panics, the browser will still be on private browsing state, which might arouse suspicion. There is no easy way around it. You can try to instruct user to clear the history afterwards, but they might not have enough time for it.
- Most of the answer focuses on desktop browsers, the experience on a mobile device will be different, but not very much.

Comment: OP asked "how to implement a panic button" and yet people seem to be answering with a tutorial on "how to safely browse the web". That's SO for you I guess, don't tell us what you need, we'll tell you.

Answer (score 4):

### Reliable Escape

**EDIT:** Another thing that comes to mind is that if the user has lost Internet connectivity, which happens for all kinds of reasons including somebody disconnecting the cable, then there is no way you could navigate them to another site. They could be stuck there like a deer in headlights on the "incriminating" page. I think this adds credibility to the idea of actually navigating to a benign partner/affiliate site that in turn loads your site in an iframe directly on their page. All you have to do to make your site disappear is delete your iframe from the DOM using JavaScript that is already loaded into the iframe. It would work even if the Internet connection went dead.

**I would enable the Escape key for a quick exit. That's a physical, well-known key on the keyboard that the user can lunge for if they need to, rather than moving a finicky mouse pointer to a virtual button and clicking.**

**EDIT:** I just realized that an earlier poster *did* mention the Escape key, referring to it as "ESC." I searched the page for "Escape key" before writing my response, but missed that.

**EDIT:** I'd leave the Panic Button on the page, too, with the text "Click Here or PRESS ESCAPE to Exit Quickly." But I'd put one at the top and one at the bottom of the page.  Maybe I'd put a strip all the way around the page. If the visitor clicks anywhere in that border zone your content disappears.

Also consider; to make the Panic Button reasonably easy to click in a panic situation, you'd probably need to make it a little bit oversized and make sure it's always on the screen by moving it as the page scrolls, or by putting multiple Panic Buttons on the page, which could be kind of suspicious-looking in and of itself. It seems as if these probably want to be pretty discrete-looking pages that you're talking about.

If you're using jQuery, you could do something like the following to respond to the Escape key:

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    $( document ).keyup( function ( e ) {
        if ( e.which === 27 ) // escape
         {
         // clean up... 
         }
    } );
} );
```

### Single-Page AJAX App

It looks like all of the suggested solutions are about figuring out some way to quickly navigate to some other site, either by having it pre-loaded and quickly displaying it over the top of your site, or by clearing the DOM then navigating away, or whatever.

If I were going to take that approach, I'd have a laundry list of universally benign sites and search engine searches that I would cycle through so that it isn't the same "search for black women's shoes" showing up every time.

**But what about turning the whole concept on its head?**  Use one or more benign decoy sites, or even solicit unrelated benign commercial sites to host a benign-looking link, and load your site as a single-page AJAX app in an iframe *on top of the host page*(s)?

**EDIT:** You could even do this by having your home page briefly state that it is going to redirect the visitor to a cooperative partner site for their own safety and show a big friendly "Go" button. If you have multiple partner sites you can push them to, so much the better. When they click, erase the browser history for your page, redirect to the affiliated site with a URL query parameter that tells your bootstrap JavaScript at the affiliate to immediately load your iframe. From that point forward, there is no additional load on the affiliate's web server. This way, you have an official Home page, but you immediately get the visitor completely off of your page.

Pressing the Escape key or clicking the Panic Button would just delete your iframe from the DOM, leaving the benign host page and no browser history. (Poof)

You could mitigate browser history issues that way since your link would run a bit of bootstrap JavaScript code and you would never actually *navigate* the browser to your site at all.

When the bootstrap link in the host page is clicked, it would insert an iframe into the DOM, float it (absolute positioning and z-order) to position it on top of the host page, then make an AJAX call to your web service to retrieve HTML content that it would load into the frame.  All additional links and/or buttons in the frame would also make AJAX calls to your service, whether posting data to the server or retrieving data for display.  You would never load an actual "page" in the user's browser at all.

Another nice aspect of this approach is that if the browser crashes or becomes unstable and has to be shut down from Task Manager, which would prevent the cleanup code from running, well that won't matter because you don't (necessarily) have anything to clean up.

### Houston...?

A few serious problems I see with *any* of these solutions off the top of my head, particularly given the context that lives may be on the line:

- cached objects (images, primarily) in the browser cache
- the router/firewall might be logging HTTP/HTTPS requests, and the victim may not know this, and nothing you do to clean up the browser will mitigate that
- there could be keylogging/screencap spyware installed on the user's machine and nothing you can do from a browser app will mitigate that
- computers crash, web browsers get flakey and crash and traces get left behind because cleanup code can't run.

As suggested by at least one other poster (honestly, I've only briefly skimmed the other posts), using browsers in secure mode should mitigate many of these scenarios. But that is a user training issue and user training can be a little crazy under the best conditions. It could be real tough to get right if the victims aren't very tech-savvy, especially if they really are in a panic-mode situation where calm thinking might be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at the "Boss" panic buttons on some old games and sites. The idea is that you could switch quickly to something innocent looking if your boss came by (of course, you have to see them approaching first!).

Almost any hurried/frenzied action when the abuser comes in is going to arouse their suspicion. Consider designing the screens so that they look like general news or the like (from a distance), with no large titles or pictures giving away their purpose. This could often allow time for a "leisurely" exit from the site, without panic. If the panic button link takes the user to, say, a bona fide news site, so much the better (if it comes up fast enough).

As others have mentioned, if the abuser becomes suspicious (and many control freaks are), there's still a history trail on the browser that they can quickly find out where the user has been. Frankly, there's not much you can do, especially if the user goes into a frenzied panic mode trying to cover their tracks, and the abuser sees this. Even if the screen itself can be refreshed to something innocent after some timeout, the browser history will have the URL.

Consider advising users to position the computer so the abuser can't sneak up on them from behind, or to go to a library or other non-private place to use this site. If the screen content is dull looking from a distance (see above), it shouldn't attract interest from others.

Good luck with this!

Comment: my answer kinda deals with the browser history issue (it's not perfect though and can probably be improved upon)

Answer (score 2):

You could show an error page instead of an actual site, which is already loaded in the background. Maybe a fake youtube or google 404 page? I think this would keep the size of the extra content to a minimum.

As others have suggested, I would also use the escape key. Reduces the change of missing it, would be a lot easier for someone with a mousepad and the user can keep his/her finger on it when he/she is just browsing through the site.

You can also use other options; a button on the page itself or let them know about other methods of escape (ctrl + w, as mentioned before).
Maybe also a gesture for the tablet users? There are probably some libraries for that.

And of course, you could change the url in the taskbar. (See other posts for code on how to do that).

**Encourage them to try the escape options out. So they know what they do and how they can react to it.**

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this differently. My Idea is as follow:

1. Show the website with only fake content (similar style and layout with the real one).
2. User needs to do certain interaction with the content to trigger step3(e.g. put XYZ in a textbox or have clicked a combination of Checkbox or RadioButton, etc.).
3. With step 2 satisfied, when user hangover certain tiny point on the page (right hand side), the page will display its real content. And the content will remain if the mouse is over it.
4. In an emergency/Panic, user can just move the mouse away from the real content, and the content will be changed back to the fake one.

Comment: ...while holding a bag of fruit on their head and singing "anchors away," otherwise the real content won't show...

Comment: @Craig, you got the idea...